# How do I back up my App's data through email?

Tags: iphone, email, core-data

I want to allow people using my app to email themselves a backup copy of all the data stored in the app.

Is it possible to email the .sqlite to an email address from in the app? I have the email side of things working but am unsure how to go about using

`[controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"RobotWithPencil.jpg"];`

to attach the .sqlite file.

Also, once I have done this, what is a good way of getting the .sqlite file back into the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app) for help exporting data.

As for as the MIME Type goes, [this site](http://groups.jonzu.com/z_apple_sqlite-mime-type.html) suggests `octet/application-stream`. (Kudos to [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ios%20mimetype%20sqlite) on both counts.)

Of course, there is the [MFMailComposer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200) if you need any clarification on that end.